# How to bind "ß" to Meta-s?

Tags: osx, emacs

I am using Carbon-Emacs on MacOS X 10.6 with the US-International keyboard layout. Usually, I can use <kbd>Alt+s</kbd> to print the letter "ß". However, Emacs interprets this as <kbd>Meta+s</kbd> and complains that there is no command bound to that shortcut. So my questions are:

1. How can I create such a shortcut?
2. Is there another way to print the character "ß"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer to 1.*

Try adding this to your emacs configuration file (should be `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or alike):

```
(define-key global-map [(meta s)] [?\u00DF])
```

Comment: When entering the shortcut I get `After 0 kbd macro iterations: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell`.

Comment: @Björn: I don't completely understand why, but it seems that a `\ ` is needed at the end.

Comment: Hm, still getting the same error.

Comment: @Björn: See my last try, if this one doesn't work, I'll give up :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your .emacs ... I don't use a Mac, so I couldn't test that side of it. However this works for me.
The original `define-key global-map` presented by *Björn Pollex* did not work for me, but his latest version using `(U+00DF)` does work (for me), I can't tell from your comments (till now), if it works for you.. If it doesn't, try this one..

```
(defun insert-sharp-s ()
  "Insert Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S' (U+00DF)"
       (interactive)
       (insert "ß")
       )
(global-set-key "\M-s" 'insert-sharp-s)
```