# What is the connection between a gedit bug and a Unix-&-Linux Q/A href?

Tags: text-processing, editors, character-encoding, unicode

While answering a *[Unix-&-Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/how-to-bind-ss-to-meta-s/17860#17860)*, I observed that Gedit and two other editors, Leafpad and Medit (I tested 12 editors altogether) exhibit the a certain bug. As it turns out, the bug is known to Canonical's launchpad as Bug #332321 *[search (and replace) takes ss as ß](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/332321)*.

The bug's behaviour is that `find ß` will match both `ß` and `ss`... (not nice, especially if you do a replace-all).

I then noticed that the StackExchange software, in order to create the question's href link, had converted the question's title from `How to bind “ß” to Meta-s?` to  `how-to-bind-ss-to-meta-s`.

So two completely unrelated environments are treating `ß` in a similar  manner.. What is this strange attraction between `ß` and `ss`? ... and are there other such 'relationships'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ß` is actually a ligature of `ss` (in German). Anybody using a a table to convert Unicode or other extended alphabet characters to "safe" characters for things like URLs will likely convert it to `ss`.

Doing this for URLs is quite normal. For example I speak Turkish, where we have letters not found in English such as `ö ü ı â ğ ç ş İ`. These characters are not always safe to use in URLs, special form fields, etc. In their place we substitute similar characters such as `o u i a g c s I`. Usually this is done by visual similarity rather than sound, but the case of `ß` the audible similarity to `ss` makes it a common conversion.

This constitutes a net-loss of data, but as a safe representation of a URL or other special field it works, then on the site itself you can use the real characters.

Why `gedit` would be doing this conversion is beyond me. It's a bug.

Comment: Again! I've got to learn to read faster :/

Comment: @Caleb: Aha! I see. It certainly makes sense with it being a ligature, thanks... (so, the gedit bug may have other clashing codepoints)...

Answer (score 4):

Case normalization. <goes to check with Gedit> Yup.

When you make a case-insensitive search, GEdit (and I presume the others) normalize the case, and this causes a number of character equivalences to collapse. For example, `ß` and `ss` both uppercase to `SS`. Composite characters such as `é` and `é` (the first is U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, the second is U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT followed by U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E) are also considered equivalent there.

If you make a case-sensitive search, these character sequences are all considered different.